# mule getting value from the url to message payload

Tags: mule

I have url as:

> localhost:8081/urltest?company=test?emplId=1234

I need to get the value of company and emplId in payload. Do I need to use transformer and get all the values or can get the values from payload in mule expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with MEL expresssion to get the values like :-

`#[message.inboundProperties['company']]` and `#[message.inboundProperties['emplId']]`

Check wheteher you are getting the values in logger like the following :-

```
<logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['company']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

and

```
<logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['emplId']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

and I beleive your url format should be like :-

```
localhost:8081/urltest/?company=test&emplId=1234
```

as I beleive `localhost:8081/urltest?company=test?emplId=1234` may not work

for your reference .. I found an article :- http://wiki.marketruler.com/What_is_the_correct_syntax_for_query_strings%3F

Answer (score 0):

use this expression you get userid from url

```
<logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['userid']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```